# Generate 3d surface plot using black and white heightmap and pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I am searching for the best way, software or script (latex, python, R, octave), to interactively draw or paint some 3D surface plot for pedagogic usage.

I finally found a way to generate and transform pdf 3D surface plot with svg export using `pgfplots` latex package. Thus I can redraw/rework initial drawing to render a graphic like this.

[image: pedagogic surface]

But I don't want to use a common mathematic function for input of the 3d drawing, I want to use, if possible, a heightmap to generate the surface.

[image]

Is it possible to transform a random black and white heightmap into a 3Dsurface plot with `pgfplots` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used `scipy` to transform the heightmap to a data matrix and then wrote the coordinates and the height values to a file.

## Exact height profile

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

matrix = misc.imread('536ws.jpg',flatten=True)
x,y = matrix.shape

mesh = ""
for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,y):
        mesh += "%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (i,j,matrix[i,j])
    mesh += "\n"

print(mesh)
```

I ran the script and piped the output to a file called `matrix.dat`

```
python extract.py > matrix.dat
```

Then I used `pgfplots` to visualise the matrix

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,colormap/blackwhite,mesh/ordering=y varies] table {matrix.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You need to use `lualatex` for this as `pdflatex` will run out of memory.  Processing this file takes ca. 1 minute and 52 seconds on my machine.

In the rendered `png` the colour map turned out darker than in the `pdf`.

> [image]

## Averaged height profile

The following script introduces some averaging over all points of the mesh (factor of 5 here).  The rest of the procedure stays the same.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

matrix = misc.imread('536ws.jpg',flatten=True)
x,y = matrix.shape
matrix = misc.imresize(matrix,(x/5,y/5))
x,y = matrix.shape

mesh = ""
for i in range(0,x):
    for j in range(0,y):
        mesh += "%d\t%d\t%d\n" % (i,j,matrix[i,j])
    mesh += "\n"

print(mesh)
```

This is now compilable with `pdflatex` (no more out-of-memory) and takes ca. 3 seconds.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Here an updated Python 3 code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
 
 import numpy as np
 
 import imageio
 
 matrix = imageio.imread('536ws.jpg', as_gray = True)
 x,y=matrix.shape
 
 mesh = ' ' 
 for i in range(0,x):
     for j in range(0,y):
         mesh += '%d \t %d \t %d \n' % (i,j,matrix[i,j])
         mesh += '\n'
 
 print(mesh)
```

To get the .dat file:

```
python3 extract.py > matrix.dat
```

The latex code is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,colormap/blackwhite,mesh/ordering=y varies] table {matrix.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the terminal:

```
lualatex file.tex
```